# checking return value of function before using result

Tags: function, lua

```
    placeholder = f()
    if placeholder then return placeholder end
```

this feels inelegant, doing such a simple task in two lines with so many words feels weird. Is there a less verbose/"better" way of writing this?

an example where this is useful is:

```
    for f in pairs(listOfFunctions) do
        placeholder  = f()
        if placeholder then return f() end
    end
```

Comment: No short cut. Such is the nature of Lua.

Comment: Can you give a larger example, with a little more context? If that's your entire function body, it could easily be reduced to `return f()` or `return f() or nil` (if you want to avoid returning `false`) considering the 'else' branch is a nothingness anyway. `return f() or (function () return .... end)()` can be used to create waterfalls, but that's slightly ugly stuff. Generally, no, there is no way to _'return result only if result'_.

Comment: Do you want efficient code or pretty code?

Answer (score 0):

Background:

- a function can have any number of return statements that return any number of values, and can vary from call to call.
- `or` is a selector operator: It returns the first non-"falsey" operand. (These second operand expression is not evaluated unless needed.)
- an expression that yields a list preserves the entire list in a list context (for example, the last expression in a list, such a return statement), but only the first value in a non-list context (for example, inside parentheses).

It's unclear which return-lists you want to return and under which conditions. What you are showing appears to be if f() returns a list with a first value neither `nil` nor `false`, return that one value; otherwise return an empty list.

But sometimes it doesn't really matter if you return lists with superfluous values, particularly a list of just `nil` instead of an empty list. Other times, it is useful to return the same number of values every time.

So, here are some alternatives.

Return all values in f()'s result-list

```
return f()
```

Or, return only the first value in f()'s result-list, `nil` if none

```
return (f())
```

Or, return the first value in f()'s result-list if it is neither `nil` nor `false`, otherwise return `nil`

```
return f() or nil
```

Or, return the first value in f()'s result-list if it is neither `nil` nor `false`, otherwise return `false`

```
return f() or false
```

If you find it awkward to have an unconditional return at that point in your code, you would need to restructure your control flow-and might, in fact, benefit from less control-flow anyway.

Comment: you miss understand, I want to either: return `f()` or continue, not return `f()` or `false`/`nil`

Comment: Yes, that's why I suggested you might have to restructure code that you haven't shown.

Comment: The code that you now show is wrapped pretty tightly into needed control flow so I can't see any direct improvement. Monad-style values and functions might lead somewhere but that would be a larger change and probably pointless.